# Xpath 'Like' operator to find value in html

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have an html page which I would like to run a xPath query against to find any elements which have the id, name etc containing or like a value e.g name = 'tv_11223344' or name = 'tv_11223344'.

Been looking on line and through some old books but I cant find anything which looks like it will help me out.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatfully looked forward to!

Comment: Are you sure your HTML page is also a valid XML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) there is [support for regular expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string.match)**.

Have a look at the standard function [**`matches()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches).